# Change variable names in a list and keep the original variable names in R

Tags: r, paste, lapply

I have a data frame data with `var1, .., var100`. They are all numeric and have the same length.

I put them into a list: `list1<-list(var1, .., var100)`.

Now, I'd like to duplicate the variables with extended names `(var1_trunc,.., var100_trunc)` and also keep the original variables `(var1,.., var100)` . I do not need `rename`, as I want to run different statistics later for `var1` vs. `var1_trunc` and so on.

I tried:

```
lapply(list1, function(x){
    paste(substitute(x),"trunc",sep="_")[x<mean(x)]<<-x
    paste(substitute(x),"trunc",sep="_")[x>=mean(x)]<<-mean(x)
    }
```

My problem is that the new variables `(var1,.., var100)` are not created.

May be I'm trying a wrong approach?

Comment: If you want to create new variable names `paste0(colnames(dat), '_trunc')`

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you put them in a list when you have a dataframe that will be easy to perform your stats comparisons later.

As @akrun mentioned you can use that command to change names.

```
 # example dataframe
df1 = data.frame(var1 = 1:5,
                 var2 = 11:15)
df1

#   var1 var2
# 1    1   11
# 2    2   12
# 3    3   13
# 4    4   14
# 5    5   15


# your function
ff = function(x){ ifelse(x < mean(x), x, mean(x)) }

# create new dataset by applying function to prevous dataset
df2 = data.frame(sapply(df1, ff))

df2

#   var1 var2
# 1    1   11
# 2    2   12
# 3    3   13
# 4    3   13
# 5    3   13

# change names and combine datasets
names(df2) = paste0(names(df1),"_trunc")
df_full = cbind(df1,df2)

df_full

#   var1 var2 var1_trunc var2_trunc
# 1    1   11          1         11
# 2    2   12          2         12
# 3    3   13          3         13
# 4    4   14          3         13
# 5    5   15          3         13
```

Use the approach above as a function that updates your datasets:

```
# your function to update dataset
UpdateDataset = function(df1){

ff = function(x){ ifelse(x < mean(x), x, mean(x)) }  # your function to update columns

df2 = data.frame(sapply(df1, ff))

names(df2) = paste0(names(df1),"_trunc")

df_full = cbind(df1,df2)

return(df_full)
                              }


# try a new dataset
df = data.frame(var1 = 1:10,
                var2 = 41:50)
df

#    var1 var2
# 1     1   41
# 2     2   42
# 3     3   43
# 4     4   44
# 5     5   45
# 6     6   46
# 7     7   47
# 8     8   48
# 9     9   49
# 10   10   50


UpdateDataset(df)

#    var1 var2 var1_trunc var2_trunc
# 1     1   41        1.0       41.0
# 2     2   42        2.0       42.0
# 3     3   43        3.0       43.0
# 4     4   44        4.0       44.0
# 5     5   45        5.0       45.0
# 6     6   46        5.5       45.5
# 7     7   47        5.5       45.5
# 8     8   48        5.5       45.5
# 9     9   49        5.5       45.5
# 10   10   50        5.5       45.5
```

Comment: to hasty, sorry. Now I have the variables with the right names. But how can I change the values of `var1_trunc` condidtional to `var1`, `var2_trunc` condidtional to `var2`  etc.?

Comment: This is easy if you give me an example.

Comment: The function should look like: `var1_trunc[var1<mean(var1)]=var1`; `var1_trunc[var1>=mean(var1)]=mean(var1)` etc. for a list of variables.

Comment: Good, I'll re-write my answer to be more automated. Looks a bit manual now.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the code and thank you for your help.

Comment: I've edited my answer already. You need indeed to create a function and use it within "sapply" to update all columns in a more automated way. Then you just cbind the dataframes. It's simple and you can have the whole process as a function. See how it works at the moment and let me know if you want me to do that.

Comment: It does what I wanted! The whole process as a function, that would great.